# cor.test correlation for 2 data frames with p-value in R

Tags: r, correlation

I have 2 data frames, which are different to each other and I need to do a correlation on those using the `cor.test()` function in `R`.

My data frame has the same number of columns but the rows are different to each other.

For instance, after melting (using the `melt()` function from the `reshape` package) my data frames look like the following:

Each of these data frames has 84 columns and varying row count:

```
head(df1)


ID  variable    value
ENSG60  AE02_ID 7.408430
ENSG53  AE02_ID 0.000000
ENSG94  AE02_ID 2.556464
ENSG49  AE02_ID 0.032384
ENSG9   AE02_ID 0.000000
```

and `head(df2)`:

```
ID  variable value
ENSG3   AE02_ID 0.000001
ENSG1   AE02_ID 0.329180
ENSG8   AE02_ID 0.000000
ENSG10  AE02_ID 29.157761
ENSG20  AE02_ID 0.633884
```

I used the following `R` script for my analysis where it returns the Spearman coefficient:

```
result <- apply(mat1, 2, function(col_mat1){
  apply(mat2, 2, function(col2, col1) {
    cor.test(col2, col1, method = "spearman")$estimate # this returns the p-value of the cor.test
  }, col1=col_mat1)
})
```

And when I tried to add a p.value to the above function as:

```
result <- apply(mat1, 2, function(col_mat1){
  apply(mat2, 2, function(col2, col1) {
    cor.test(col2, col1, method = "spearman")cbind($estimate,$p.value) # this returns the p-value of the cor.test
  }, col1=col_mat1)
})
```

it's returning an error message.

Any suggestions or help would be great. Thank you. The desired out is something like this,

```
    df1     df2     Coefficient     P.value
    ENSG60  ENSG3   0.1828591281    0.00546547
    ENSG53  ENSG1   0.021038182 0.021038182
    ENSG94  ENSG8   -0.0683044433   0.000657
```

Comment: Is this a statistics question or a programming/debugging question?

Comment: The problem is purely syntactic which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Jon, Its a debugging question as I am not getting what I am asking for and I would like to ask in forum. If you could guide me a little bit would be great

Comment: How does your above dfs relate to your bottom mats? I see only 3 columns, not 84. And what is your desired result? Vector? List? Matrix? Dataframe? One column of estimates and other p-values?

Comment: The desired output is one column with Estimate and other with p-value as a matrix or dataframe

Comment: And my first question? How do above dfs relate to bottom mats? What reproducible data do we use to help? You need to pass vector of values, not scalars in `cor.test()`. Dfs carry only one value column.

Comment: yes, so The 84 column file is melted as what i have shown in my question .  I transpose the data frames (84 column one) before applying it to the function. As mat1 <- t(mRNA)
mat2 <- t(lncRNA) then apply it to my functions I defined in my question

Comment: dim(mat1) 
[1]  82 407 and  dim(mat2)  [1]  82 288 So both datafarmes are of differrent size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given a reproducible example, but I think your inner function needs to be modified slightly (e.g.) as follows:

```
function(col2, col1) {
    cc <- cor.test(col2, col1, method = "spearman")
    cbind(cc$estimate,cc$p.value)
}
```